# Why Facebook isn't picking up the open graph tags

Tags: wordpress, facebook, debugging, twitter, woocommerce

Site runs on Wordpress + WooCommerce, I've been trying to fix this for a while. I have setup an app on Facebook and using Open Graph and Twitter Card Tags (2.2.7.2) plugin to add the data to my site.  Both Facebook and twitter debuggers don't pick up the information. I tested the tags on a third party app, and it gets all the data. See the links below.

URL: [product page](https://kave.men/shop/citrus-mint-beard-oil/)

[Third party app test](https://opengraphcheck.com/result.php?url=https%3A%2F%2Fkave.men%2Fshop%2Fcitrus-mint-beard-oil%2F#.XkWcaS2B06g)

Comment: That is because the information is not there. This is what you send back to Facebook when they scrape your page: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/echo/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fkave.men%2Fshop%2Fcitrus-mint-beard-oil%2F

Comment: Provide the steps you've done so far to fix it or what kind of social SEO solution you're using (if it's your custom built, please provide some code examples). As @WizKid mentioned - the information clearly is not there, so check the outputing part of code in the solution.